# AttributeError: 'ActivitiesClient' object has no attribute 'base_url'

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, attributeerror

I know it's a quite well-answered question, yet after going through many of the questions, I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.

So my script is like this:

```
import json

from config import BASE_URL
from utils.request import APIRequest


class ActivitiesClient:
    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.base_url = BASE_URL + "Activities"
        self.request = APIRequest()

    def create_activity(self, payload):
        return self.request.post_request(
            self.base_url, json.dumps(payload))

    def get_all_activities(self):
        # return self.request.get_request(self.base_url)
        return APIRequest().get_request(self.base_url)


print(ActivitiesClient().get_all_activities())
```

and from which I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Pract/APIAutomationProject/services/activities_services.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(ActivitiesClient().get_all_activities())
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Pract/APIAutomationProject/services/activities_services.py", line 19, in get_all_activities
    return APIRequest().get_request(self.base_url)
AttributeError: 'ActivitiesClient' object has no attribute 'base_url'
```

Where I am making a mistake, and I am asking this, so that I can understand my solution as well.

Comment: You have a typo in your `def __int__`. It should be `def __init__`.

Comment: Got it... It was an honest mistake... Thanks for figuring out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your constructor to `__init__` (not `__int__`):

```py
import json

from config import BASE_URL
from utils.request import APIRequest


class ActivitiesClient:
    def __init__(self):   # <--- __init__ , not __int__
        super().__init__()
        self.base_url = BASE_URL + "Activities"
        self.request = APIRequest()

    def create_activity(self, payload):
        return self.request.post_request(self.base_url, json.dumps(payload))

    def get_all_activities(self):
        # return self.request.get_request(self.base_url)
        return APIRequest().get_request(self.base_url)


print(ActivitiesClient().get_all_activities())
```

Comment: Oh Man, how can I be that blind... Thanks for the answer man.. @Andrej